# echo *, can't find out what it does

Tags: shell, wildcards

I have a book that says that the output of the command `echo *` is the line that follows below. I can't find why it outputs that. Please help.

```
$ echo *
local.cshrc local.login local.profile
```

Comment: Bash globbing and filename expansion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is shell special character (glob match) that matches the names of files and directories in the current directory.

```
$ ls *
```

This will list all files and directories in current directory.
So, in your case '*' returns and 'echo' prints them on the console.
Try this to confirm:

```
$ x=*
$ echo $x
```

Comment: `ls *` is slightly different from `echo *`; `mkdir p; touch p/j`

Comment: Agree. ls * will also display the content of first level subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [wildcard](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) - `*` which is used with `globbing` and `file-expansion`.

The referenced link above describes this further:

> Standard wildcards (also known as globbing patterns) are used by various command-line utilities to work with multiple files. For more information on standard wildcards (globbing patterns) refer to the manual page by typing:

and

> `*` (asterisk) this can represent any number of characters (including zero, in other words, zero or more characters). If you specified a
>   "cd*" it would use "cda", "cdrom", "cdrecord" and anything that starts
>   with “cd” also including “cd” itself. "m*l" could by mill, mull, ml,
>   and anything that starts with an m and ends with an l.